# On the Riemann integrability of three specific discontinous functions

Tags: real-analysis

I am struggling with how to use the definition of  Riemann integral to prove that certain discontinuous function are or aren't integrable, namely functions that take the value of 0 except for at a few individual points.

So say f maps from $[0,1]$ to R, and is defined by being 0 for all x in this interval except when x=0.5 where it equals 1. Intuitively the integral of f between 0 and 1 must be zero. But surely by the definition of a Riemann integral this function isn't integrable, as for an interval (xn, xn+1) that contains $=0.5$ sup(f)=1 but inf(f) =0, so the lower and upper integrals aren't equal and hence the function isn't integrable.

Also I have a proof showing that the function on the interval [0,1] that takes the value 1 if x is rational and 0 otherwise is not an integrable function which makes sense. But then I have a found a problem that asks to prove that the function on the interval [0,1] that takes the value 1/p when x is rational (where x=q/p in its most reduced form) and zero otherwise. Surely is one of these two functions is integrable then the other is as well? And surely the integral over [0,1] is zero?

I also know that any piecewise continuous function is integrable, surely a function that is made up of singleton points is just piecewise continuous in the most extreme sense?

I apologise that my formatting is terrible.

Comment: After nine questions asked I think there's no need to apologize for the formating: learn the easy rules to properly write mathematics in this site instead. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference

Answer (score 2):

Note that for any particular partition, the upper and lower sums will usually not coincide, even for integrable functions.  The point, intuitively, is that forcing the mesh of the partitions (defined as the maximum of the $|x_{n+1}- x_n|$) to be small will force the upper and lower sums to get closer together.

For the first example, the difference between the lower and upper sums will be $x_{n+1} - x_n$, which will approach zero as you use finer and finer partitions.  The fact that the discontinuity is at a single point means that it doesn't really affect the integral.  Having lots of discontinuities (like the second example, where everything is discontinuous), on the other hand, can pose a problem.

The third example you cite is tricky.  It's not too hard to show that this function is continuous at irrational points (unlike in the second example), which indicates that it might be possible to integrate.

Comment: For the third example, one may note that $f(x)\geqslant\varepsilon$ only at a finite number of points $x$, and this suffices to show that $f$ is Riemann integrable with integral $0$.

Comment: How can the function be continuous at irrational points? Surely between any two irrational numbers you can find a rational number?

Comment: Yes you can find rational numbers in any interval, but if you consider smaller and smaller intervals around an irrational point, the denominators can be forced to get larger and larger.  As above, $f(x) \ge \epsilon$ at only finitely many points, so just choose a $\delta >0$ small enough that none of those points are within $\delta$ of your irrational $x$.

Comment: Lebesgue's criterion implies that the last function is indeed Riemann integrable. Rolf's argument lets you write this out without proving the Lebesgue criterion in general.

Comment: true, but that is going to be hard to prove rigorously as sometimes the numerator and denominator will cancel, but ok thanks, I  can see what you mean.

Comment: Sorry Ian, didn't see your comment. I will look up Lebesgue's criterion. I think I understand now where my misunderstanding lay. My only last question is, is the Riemann integral only defined if the limit as the size of the mesh tends to zero of the upper and lower integral are the same? Do you have to take the limit as the mesh tends to zero?

Comment: Do you mean upper and lower sums when you say 'upper and lower integral'?  You have to take the limit, otherwise you could take a non-constant function like $f(x) = x$, and see directly that any particular upper sum is strictly larger than the corresponding lower sum.

Comment: Yes sorry I did, and yeah I see now. Intuitively it made sense my notes just didn't say it but now I realised they did just not so explicitly which probably didn't help my confusion.

Comment: Though for the  third example if is integrable is the value of the integral slightly greater than zero?

Comment: Nope, the lower sums are always zero, so if the integral exists it must be zero.